# AEM as a cloud | site page is not opening in live copies console since it has large amount of data

Tags: aem

Steps to check:

1. Go to https://{author-env}.adobeaemcloud.com/sites.html/content
2. From top right corner select references from the dropdown.
3. Now select checkbox of the hierarchy/page for which you want to see the live copies.
   Eg:/sites.html/content/{project-name}/us/en/page
4. Once you select any page you will see live copies option on the left panel.
5. Then just select the Live copies option.
6. From there, check the bottom of the left panel where “Live Copy Overview” button is present.
7. Just click on it and you will redirect on required console. Now check for the page.
   https://{author-env}.adobeaemcloud.com/libs/wcm/msm/gui/content/livecopies.html/content{<project-name}/us/en/page

**Actual**: page is not opening in live copies console since it has large amount of data.
**Expected**: All pages should be opened in the live copies console.

I tried above steps in my local, there live copy console opened successfully. What is the exact issue and is there any workaround this issue?

Comment: Frankly speaking, the format of this question is more like a bug report than a question, indicating we (the community) are responsible for the fact it does not work, whereas the steps are correct.

Comment: Yes, in title mention the actual issue that I am facing and I mention the steps how to check the error. Now my question is, I am not able to figure out the exact root cause and what would the workaround for this issue?

Comment: You need to import the content from that server to replicate the issue, a local server with dummy or outdated content probably will work just fine and you will be able to debug and see if in fact that page has a lot of components or a component getting too much data, etc.